# Turn / Transform simple textarea into CKEditor and vice versa - Solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, ckeditor

I am properly using CKEditor. But All on a sudden felt to leave a toggle option to user (CKEditor to/from Simple Textarea) & the snippet is shared in below.

Answer (score 1):

> ... Initialise CKEditor  '**yourCkEditor**' and then append following snippets

HTML

```
<a onclick="ckToggle()">Toogle Text area </a>
```

JS

```
<script>
    var ckFlag=1;
    function ckToggle(){
            flag = 1-ckFlag;
            if(flag==1){
                CKEDITOR.replace('yourCkEditor');
                ckFlag=1;
            }         
            else{
                CKEDITOR.instances['yourCkEditor'].destroy(true);
                ckFlag=0;
            }
        }
</script>
```